# Total space in bkps using rsync and hardlinks: who is right between du and Synlogy web interface?

Tags: backup, nfs, rsync, synology, hardlink

I bkp my server root partition on a Synology NAS (fs: btrfs) mounted as NFS on `/mnt/bkps` using [this script](https://lobianco.org/antonello/personal/portfolio/rsync-python-script) that is based on rsync and hard links, to to have daily bkps.

If I check the space using `du` on the server it seems everything is working well, each daily backup folder is 28 GB, but the total size is only 29 GB:

```
root@ncy-beta-compserver:/mnt/bkps/root_bkps# du -hs bkps-root.2024-2-12
28G bkps-root.2024-2-12
root@ncy-beta-compserver:/mnt/bkps/root_bkps# du -hs bkps-root.2024-2-11
28G bkps-root.2024-2-11
root@ncy-beta-compserver:/mnt/bkps/root_bkps# cd ..
root@ncy-beta-compserver:/mnt/bkps# du -hs root_bkps/
29G root_bkps/
```

However if I go to the Synology NAS web interface -> File station and select "property" for the folder, I then get each daily bkp folder 28 GB, but the total bkp folder 55 GB!

Who is right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`du -hs` is right. The Syslogy WebUI is probably not hardlink-aware.

You can double check this by monitoring the volume free space.

Comment: Yes you are right, checking the shared folder size in `Control Panel` returns the `du` size. Good news :-)